# What is boost serialized map load time?

Tags: c++, optimization, serialization, boost

If a map is binary serizaled in boost is the time to load nlogn or is it n ?

If map is simply written one element at a time then loading n items seems that it would take nlogn because we are inserting n items and each item takes logn time.

But I was wondering if the map could be written in a format that matches the memory layout and the pointers marshelled.  So loading it then I would think would take n time.  Essentially memory layout is being loaded.

Does anyone have experience in this area ?

Comment: Time is not measured in `n` or `nlogn`. If you want to measure actual time you just need some profiler or a least something like `chrono::high_resolution_clock`.

Comment: If you included code, we could actually suggest changes that improve the perf. Now we're even guessing about what your map contains. Not useful

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked the source code, but...

If I were writing the serialisation code for a `std::map`, I would remember that when writing the data, it will be ordered by the comparison function (usually `std::less`).

I would then remember that `std::map::insert` has a version that allows me to specify a hint as to where the start the search for the insertion point.

Recalling that data being read from the archive is in 'ascending' order, all I would need to do is:

```
while(read_count--)
{
  std::pair<K,V> entry;
  archive >> entry;
  mymap.insert(std::end(mymap), entry);
}
```

So in reality it will be linear time.

Answer (score 0):

Like Richard says, but I'd prefer `boost::container::flat_map`. This has constructors that allow you to insert ranges that you know are already ordered: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_map.html#idp38577632-bb

I don't think the default serialization takes advantage of that, so you might want to roll your own based on that.

As a bonus: if your key/value pairs are selfcontained and POD, you can serialize them as such.